# How to use WCSession didReceiveMessage to receive different messages?

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2, wcsession

I need to send different messages from different buttons. How do I use `didReceiveMessage` to receive them all?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make an effort to try this yourself, then post your code. Questions asking for tutorials are off-topic.  See [ask] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

**`didReceiveMessage` being called**

According to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com):

> `didReceiveMessage` is called every time a new mesage is received from
>   `WatchConnectivity` on Apple Watch.

You could use its argument to check the message, and you could add an entry to the dictionary passed by `WCSession` to check the source. For example if the argument is called `message`, you can use the following code:

**Swift**

```
switch message["source"] {
    case "button1" : print("Source is button 1")
    case "button2" : print("Source is button 2")
    default : break
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
switch (message[@"source"]){
    case @"button1" : NSLog(@"Source is button 1"); break;
    case @"button2" : NSLog(@"Source is button 2"); break;
}
```

So you could use one `didReceiveMessage` method to receive all different messages from different buttons.

**Conclusion**

1- `didReceiveMessage` is called every time a message is coming.

2- You could use its argument to check the message.

3- You could use one `didReceiveMessage` method to receive all different messages from different buttons.